# How to troubleshoot silently failing js in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, firebug, unobtrusive-javascript, infinite-scroll

It should be noted that I am not very proficient at using Firebug, but I haven't found any errors that explain the following issue.

I have a `feed.js.erb` file containing the following code:

```
var $foos = $('<%= escape_javascript(render(@foos)) %>');
$('#container').append($foos);
$('#pagination_button a').attr('href', '<%= feed_path + '?page=' + @page %>');
```

When this ajax call is made ***the second time***, it appears to fail silently. I see the appropriate response in the Firebug console, but **`$foos` is not altered** and subsequently the `#container` is never appended.

My html page only includes a loading indicator, which it successfully replaces on the first call. The second call is triggered from other javascript ([Infinite Scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/)).

If it matters, I have noticed that the first call is made with an automatically generated timestamp parameter. After that I am replacing the target url as you can see on my `#pagination_button a`.

How can I debug this in the browser?

***Update***: I used ERB to make `$foos` a dynamic variable ($foos1...$foos2) and noticed that this is also not working. So even though the new `@foos` are visible in the console's response, the first line of my javascript is not being evaluated.

Comment: How about placing a breakpoint on one of those lines using the firebug script panel?

Comment: I can't find a way to do that because this script is inside of an http response. It is created dynamically by my Rails controller well after the html page is already rendered.

Comment: You're not trying to append the to the container twice with the same element-id, are you?

Comment: Yes, in different calls. It is appended once on ajax success. Then a new ajax request fails to append it.

Comment: If you're not modifying the id on the second call, then that's the issue.  Element id's are supposed to be unique within the DOM, and browsers will fail in a variety of ways if you try to add two or more elements with the same id.  So you need to use a different id on each element that you append, or to ensure that you explicitly remove the first element from the DOM before you append the second.  Either approach should work.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Perhaps we miscommunicated. The `@foos` do not use an `#element-id`. They are all members of a `.class`. I am simply inserting new children into the parent container. And as you can see from my update, the problem seems to occur before the `append()` anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, Rails is not processing my second request as JS. More importantly, if the JS raises an exception, it will be converted to plain-text [as explained here](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-js-erb-remote-response-not-executing/). [Steve](http://twitter.com/jangosteve) also shows how to debug ajax code, effectively answering both of my questions.