# Script retrieved via Getscript Fails Silently - how to troubleshoot this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am running a script after a page loads.  This cannot be done via precompiled asset-pipeline, because ruby variables generated in the controller on page-load are used in the script.  Here is a simplified version of how I am calling the script:

```
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
  var url = "/assets/foo/bar.js";
  $(window).on('load', function(){
    console.log('page-loaded and url is: ' + url);
    $.getScript( url, function() {
      console.log('loaded bar.js');
    });
  });
</script>
```

The behavior is that the first console.log fires on page-load, but the second one within getScript never runs.

As I have the url shown in the first console log, I can take the value shown in the console-output, paste it in my browser's address bar (after the domain name), and successfully load the script into a page as text - so no problem with the url reference.

Next, I reduced the script (bar.js, in this example) to a single console.log statement outputting my ruby-variable.  This works, so there must be an error somewhere in my original js, yet no error is shown in any console output.

How can I troubleshoot this javascript, absent so much as an error-type/line# showing up in either the javascript console (in firefox dev-tools) OR in the rails console?  Does Rails log the error somewhere else?

Note that there is no indication in the rails-console that getScript did/loaded anything - either with the working script or the mysteriously-broken script, as there would be if this were an ajax call like this question:

[How to troubleshoot silently failing js in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576077/how-to-troubleshoot-silently-failing-js-in-rails)

I'm not including the js file, because I do not need help troubleshooting javascript *if* I can get feedback as to the nature of the error.  How do I get the error to show up somewhere?

EDIT - I tried pasting the script inline, in place of the 'getScript' call.  It still fails silently.  The only difference is that I get the first console.log() output from *within* the script, and some other stuff on the page breaks, which worked before, indicating a js error, which remains an unreported mystery.

EDIT #2:

The Three Errors from @jfriend00 suggestion #9 are:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Stack trace:
.globalEval/<@http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/jquery.js?body=1:339:5
.globalEval@http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/jquery.js?body=1:340:1
.converters["text script"]@http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/jquery.js?body=1:9739:4
ajaxConvert@http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/jquery.js?body=1:8809:8
done@http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/jquery.js?body=1:9226:4
.send/callback@http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/jquery.js?body=1:9686:8
 new:234
Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: .ajax/jqXHR.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/jqXHR.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/jqXHR.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/jqXHR.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/jqXHR.abort(), state: .Deferred/promise.state(), always: .Deferred/promise.always(), then: .Deferred/promise.then(), 11 more… } new:235

"parsererror"
```

It would be nice to know WHICH statement is missing a semicolon (I don't see any missing), or if this error is within the parser itself, due to something in the script which causes a mis-parse.

Edit #3 - more @jfriend00 suggestions tried
If I put the script inline, so as to make #11 possible, because my script calls another jquery function, consisting of thousands of lines. Would be great for a little-script with no externals, though.

For #10 - I put a console.log() at the end.  The inline version runs to the end and displays that output, but just doesn't do anything else it is supposed to do.  Yet the getScript method never runs or calls-back anything, except via the error-method (listed above in Edit #2), verifying an error is detected in that case.  IOW, the identical script-code 'runs but does not work' inline, but 'errors-out' if retrieved by getScript.

I suppose I will just have to place all my page-specific scripts inline and accept the ugliness.  I can then just do the 'binary search' method with adding console.log()s to output every possible bit of data, at each stage, given it is random-chance guessing to determine which setting/value is causing any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's no way we can actually know what is causing the problem, about the best we can do is to list a bunch of things for you to check:

1. Is your script doing any `document.write()` calls because doing so after the doc has finished loading will clear the current document and obscure what's going on.
2. Is it possible that the script you're loading doesn't actually do anything other than define functions that are waiting to be called.
3. Have you tried loading your script with a static script tag just to see if it works that way?  This would also put it at the top level (not in the bowels of `$.getScript()` where you might be more likely to see any script errors.
4. Are you 200% sure that yo have the path correct when passed to `$.getScript()`?
5. Have you looked in the network tab in the Chrome debugger to see what is actually being requested and returned from your server?  You should see the request going out and a response coming back.
6. Have you cleared the browser cache in case an old, perhaps empty version of the file is stuck in the cache?  The network tab in Chrome would also tell you whether the file was being loaded from the server or from the cache.  You can, add a random number to the URL to defeat caching:

   `var url = "/assets/foo/bar.js?" + Math.random();`
7. It takes some time, but you can step through `$.getScript()` in an unminimized version of jQuery.  You will have to figure out where to set breakpoints because the response come back asynchronously, but that would eventually let you see exactly what response it got and what is was doing with that response.
8. If you put a completion callback on `$.getScript()` as the 2nd argument, what do the arguments to that callback report?

   `$.getScript(url, function(data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
       console.log(textStatus);
       console.log(data);
       console.log(jqXhr);
   });`
9. If you set an error handler on the `$.getScript()`, does that get called?

   `$.getScript(url).fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception) {
       console.log(exception);
       console.log(jqxhr);
       console.log(settings);
    });`
10. If you've determined that your script is starting to execute, but then failing, you can debug that script.  The simple way to do so is to sprinkle it with unique `console.log()` statements so you can see exactly how far it's getting and iterate to a finer and finer level of line number until you've narrowed down exactly where it is failing (essentially a binary search).
11. You can also put a `debugger;` statement in the dynamically loaded script near the top of the script to trigger the debugger and then you can step through the rest of your script to see where it fails.

Comment: Added several more debugging ideas.

Comment: 1. No;  2. No; 3. Tried Inline (see edit); 4 -> 6. Verified with network 200-success for "http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/foo/bar.js?_=1413869878924" - rails is defeating caching with the param; 8 -> 11 Look like the only way to debug.  I hadn't seen some of those ideas before. Thank You.

Comment: Marking this as "the answer" because it gave some useful workarounds to the Total Absence of Sane Error-Reporting, because no one else even bothered to try, and because an honest 'no answer exists' means few will help me in the future.  Many of my difficult questions are tumbleweeds, and most SO people see that reflected in my profile, and look for "easier points," rather than challenges.  Thank you jfriend00, for your input and courage.